# What does "dumping on me" mean?

Tags: meaning

I'm watching documentary about vet. There are some sick cows. and owner said this.

> Black one's kind of dumping on me.

The cow was just lying on the ground. I searched for dumping on, but it's usually about being harsh to someone. or make someone does hard things. I can't find one exactly fit for this situation.

What does this mean? Does this mean cow fell down? or cow attacked the owner? or Cow is sick so that's the burden for the owner? or Cow take a dump, throw up or something?

Comment: That  sentence is **not right**. Black's one? You have misheard it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Without seeing the documentary, it's not clear which of two senses the owner means.

The more likely, I think, is this:

1. The black one is kind of *dumping* [falling clumsily to the ground] *on me* [with a consequent negative effect on me].

Here, the verb is *dump* in a metaphorical sense: fall down; and *on me* is not part of a phrasal verb, but a sort of benefactive.  Compare *Don't black out on me* (don't lose consciousness and thereby cause me a problem), *She bailed on me* (she abandoned our date and thereby let me down).

It's conceivable, but less likely, that the owner meant:

2. The black one is kind of *dumping on* [defecating on] me.

Here, the metaphor is that, by doing something disadvantageous to me (by being sick), it's like the cow is defecating on me.  I think this meaning is much less likely.

Comment: No, it does not mean defecating on me. To do something on me, means to occur in a situation that affects me. As in: The kids are misbehaving **on me**. My wife is cheating on me.

Comment: Perhaps you have never heard anyone say "X dumped on me", meaning "put me in a bad situation".  I have.

Comment: Yes, sure. I  just gave you an example: The kids are dumping on me.